# Do these functions have an holomorphic extension to $0$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to know if the following functions have an holomprohic extension to $0$ or not:

(a) $\frac{z}{e^z-1}$.

(b) $z^2 \sin \frac{1}{z}$.

For (b) I think it does because for $0<|z|<1$, $|z^2 \sin \frac{1}{z}| \le 1 \cdot 1 = 1$. So the function is bounded in a punctured neighborhood of $0$ and then there is an holomoprhic extension to $0$. Is this correct?

For (a) I haven't been able to find a bound, nor to express it in its Taylor series to find the radius of convergence. What can I do here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a):

Try to calculate the limit using L'hospital's theorem:

$\lim_{z \to o} \frac{z}{e^z-1} $

For b):

If you look at the power-series of the sine-function:

$sin(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^kz^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}$

you can see that $sin(\frac{1}{z})$ got an essentially singularity in $0$. So $z^2sin(\frac{1}{z})$ cant be have a holomorphic extension in $0$!

Comment: I'm sorry but I haven't seen the topic of types of singularities. Is there another way to argue (b)?

Comment: In simple words: Using the power-series of sine you can see that there are infinite many addends in the form $\frac{1}{z^k}$. So after multiplication with $z^2$ we still have infinite many of those addends.

Answer (score 0):

Can you see why $\frac{e^z-1}{z}$ is holomorphic and nonvanishing at $0$?  What does that say about its reciprocal?

Be careful with $z^2\sin(\frac{1}{z})$. If $z$ is small, $\frac{1}{z}$ is very large in modulus.  What kind of singularity does $\sin$ have at infinity?

To explore how these functions look, check out https://people.math.osu.edu/fowler.291/phase/?  which draws phase plots for you.  Especially, try zooming in on the $\sin$ example at the origin.

Comment: I haven't seen the topic of types of singularities, I guess I should be able to do this without using that.

Comment: Well just try looking at the laurant series of $z^2\sin(1/z)$ (just plug $1/z$ into the power series of $\sin$).  Does this look holomorphic?  Do you see why your reasoning about this function in the OP is incorrect?

Comment: You might also want to look at the statement and proof of the "removable singularities theorem".

Comment: Oh I see what might be bugging you:  It is not true that $|\sin(z)| < 1$ everywhere on the complex plane.  If it were, it would be a bounded holomorphic function, which must be constant by Louville's theorem.  So in fact the modulus of $\sin(z)$ is unbounded on the complex plane.  Can you see this from the definition of complex sine?